# Unable to load win32/api.so from ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, winapi

The command run the following :

C:\V4\framework\scripts > ruby SCM.rb

The error I get is the following :

C:/Rubby/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require: 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Rubby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/win32-api-1.4.8-x86-mingw32/lib/win32/ruby19/win32/api.so (LoadError)
        from C:/Rubby/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Rubby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/win32-api-1.4.8-x86-mingw32/lib/win32/api.rb:2:in

The first few lines of the calling script looks like following :

```
require 'watir/win32ole'
require 'windows/com'
require 'windows/window/message'
```

The second line is giving the Load Error. I googled and am not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue , I got resolved this by download the zip file of api.dll from https://www.dll-files.com/api.dll.html and extract the zip file and then paste the 'api.dll' inside my ruby bin folder : "C:\Ruby22\bin